# I need display data in "divGrid" on change value in drop down list outside div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need show the divGrid when the value is not equal to zero in selected drop down list, using jquery

Comment: How can we answer this question? It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for :

```
<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

```
<div id="divGrid">
    <div id="divGrid">
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$("#divGrid").hide();
$("#test").on("change",function(){
    var type = $("#test").val();
    if(type != '0'){
        $("#divGrid").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: My drop down implementation is in this way:                                       SiteName: @Html.DropDownList("SID", new SelectList(@ViewBag.SiteTypes, "SID", "SiteName"), "-select SiteName-", new {
                              @value = "0",
                              autocomplete = "off",
                              tabindex = 1,
                              //maxlength = "9",
                              onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action='/Attendance/Index2';
            form.submit();"
                          })